# Appropriate statistical test for group discrete data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I would like to ask what would be the appropriate test to compare mean/median of groups with different number of samples for example:

A: 5%, 10%
B: 3%, 2%, 10%, 12%
C: 20%,25%, 30:
D: 40%, 30%, 25%, 20%

Because A has only 2 input, would Wilcoxon test be appropriate (as data will be non-parametric)?

Thanks

Comment: Are $A, ~B, ~C, ~D$ samples? What is $\%$ supposed to be?

Comment: How are these percentages obtained? are they count-proportions (a count divided by a total count), converted to a percentage, or are they some other form of percentage (e.g. a percentage of land area that is cultivated, which would not be a scaled count)

Comment: It's a count proportion

Comment: ABCD are conditions, % are for each samples